# How to right align a view using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, label

I have created a label and wish to align it to the right, how can I do so?

Label code:

```
echo form_label('Name', "Name: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rikesh had it almost right. It should be:

```
$attributes = array(
    'style' => 'align:right'
);
echo form_label('Name', 'Name:', $attributes);
```